# alternatives to add NTFS support to Android kernel

Tags: external-sd, file-system, ntfs

I would like to enjoy of NTFS support for my Android device. The [USB-OTG Helper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1802740) app and also [this patch - sdcardfs.ko](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/ntfs-mount-tool-android-t2920856) couldn't help with that.

With regard the patch `sdcardfs.ko`, I have done all the given instructions successfully, but when I do `su -c "insmod /system/lib/modules/sdcardfs.ko"`, I get error `Invalid argument`. I would happy about this method if it worked for me. So, it will be great if you know how I can fix this error.

My device configurations are as bellow:

- Device model: `HUAWEI G630-u10`
- Android version: 4.3
- Kernel version: 3.4.0+ (Stock Rom)
- Device is `Locked`
- Device is rooted by `KingRoot` app

Other solutions available but not interested:

- `Paragon USB plugin` for `Total Commander` (I am not interested in this method because I want NTFS support to the Android kernel so that I can access NTFS-formatted sdcards from within my favorite file manager.
- `[Paragon exFAT, NTFS, HFS+][3]` and [Ntfs Mounter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kwull.ntfsmounter&hl=en) - 'Play Store' knows these apps incompatible with my device. So, I cannot use these methods too.

Appreciate if you help to fix the problem using `sdcardfs.ko` patch as already mentioned above or introduce me other alternatives.

**Update:**
As a new try, I unlocked my device bootloader, installed TWRT and SuperSU (instead of using KingRoot method); but I'm still getting error `Invalid argument` when trying to load the `sdcardfs.ko`. So, my device configuration has changed to:

- Device is `Unlocked`
- Device is rooted - `SuperSU` installed.

Check out the [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/8FWTKS0A).